# Function of matrices in Maxima

Tags: python, matrix, sage, maxima, wxmaxima

I have two matrices Ac and Ep and a parameter k. I need to implement this matrix, which is a function of my prior matrices and k :

```
ProbEnt(k)[i,j] := if (k < wmax) then binomial(Ac[i,j], k)*Ep[i,j]^k * (1-Ep[i,j])^(Ac[i,j]-k)  else 0;
```

For some reason it will not allow me to define (build) ProbEnt parameter-wise. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the function `genmatrix` might work for you. The first argument of `genmatrix` is a function which takes two arguments, `i` and `j`, which you can use to define the `i, j` element you want.

In this case it might be something like

```
myfunction (i, j) := if k < wmax then <stuff about Ac and Ep here> else 0);
genmatrix (myfunction, mm, nn);
```

where `mm` and `nn` are the numbers of rows and columns you want.